# Permission error when using Snyk for gradle wrapper in GitLab

Tags: java, gradle, npm, gitlab, snyk

I am trying to integrate Snyk into my GitLab CI pipeline. I install it with npm, authenticate with my personal token and run `snyk test`. I get the following error which prevents me from getting the results:

```
    Testing /builds/User/pipeline...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5-all.zip
................................................................................

Unzipping /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.5-all/cg9lyzfg3iwv6fa00os9gcgj4/gradle-4.5-all.zip to /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.5-all/cg9lyzfg3iwv6fa00os9gcgj4
Set executable permissions for: /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.5-all/cg9lyzfg3iwv6fa00os9gcgj4/gradle-4.5/bin/gradle


ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```